# Using route decorator in a Flask blueprint's submodule

Tags: python, flask

I have a blueprint located in `/mybp` folder and I want to declare views in different files inside this folder:

```
/mybp/__init__.py
/mybp/some_views.py
/mybp/some_other_views.py
```

What is the best way to make possible the use of `@mybp.route()` decorator in files other than `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to import the `mybp` object in your other modules:

```
from mybp import mybp
```

or using a [relative import reference](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

```
from . import mybp
```

If you import `some_views` and `some_other_views` in `__init__`, do so *after* creating the `mybp` `Blueprint` instance.

Also see the *Circular Imports* section in the [*Larger Applications* chapter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/#simple-packages) of the Flask documentation.

Comment: Thanks. What I did wrong was to `import some_views` before creating `mybp` instance.